# how to set the escape character for Snowsql export

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am exporting a table from Snowflake to a local folder using Snowsql in a tab delimited format. In the Snowflake table one of the column values contains a tab value (char(9)) which I would like to retain in the output. However, Snowsql seems to automatically escape it. Is there a way to set the escape character to none for Snowsql exports?

e.g.
Here is some test data to replicate the issue:

```
create or replace table test as 
select '1234'as col1, 'test'||char(9)||'data' as col2
union
select '2468', 'more_test_data';
```

You can see we have a tab value in col2 for the first record.
Now if we try to export using snowsql:

```
snowsql -c [config_file_name] -d [database] -s [schema] -q "select * from test" -o output_format=tsv -o header=false -o timing=false -o friendly=false  > C:\Users\user\snowsql\test.txt:
```

When opened, the export file shows:

[image]

Any ideas of how I can force the output to be like this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try "output_format=plain"?

```
snowsql -c [config_file_name] -d [database] -s [schema] -q "select * from test" -o output_format=plain -o header=false -o timing=false -o friendly=false  > C:\Users\user\snowsql\test.txt:
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#output-format

Comment: this will retain the tab value in the data but I want the entire file to be tab separated too, and using output_format=plain unfortunately doesn't do that (it seems to automatically use double space separated by default)

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution based on the encoding of the file specified in this doc. https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SnowSQL-Non-ASCII-whitespace-characters-are-displayed-as-Unicode-escape-sequences-in-CSV-TSV-format.

Try this output instead:

`SNOWSQL_OUTPUT_AS_UNICODE=true snowsql -c [config_file_name] -d [database] -s [schema] -q "select * from test" -o output_format=tsv -o header=false -o timing=false -o friendly=false  > C:\Users\user\snowsql\test.txt`

Sample Output with Tab:

[image: sample output with tab]

Comment: good find! however, in your export if you count the number of characters between 'test' and 'data' (e.g. put your cursor at the after 'test' and hit the right arrow key), it should be 1 as it's meant to be a tab, but I find that it still stores it as multiple spaces

Comment: I am seeing it as a true tab. there is one block of space to highlight, not three individual spaces like before. I should note I am also on a Mac. Are you in notepad++?

Comment: As I see, in the first line, even the delimiter turns into "multiple spaces" after setting the parameter. In the second line, the delimiter is a real tab. You can copy-paste the output to sublime (or any other editor) to see the difference.